# Вывод текста из input каждый раз на новую строку без удаления предыдущей

Tags: javascript, input, button, ul, li

Всем привет.
Помогите, пожалуйста, подправить код. Сейчас после нажатия на кнопку каждое слово из input выводится в отдельный li, при этом после повторного нажатия текст из li удаляется. Необходимо при нажатии на кнопку весь текст из input переносить на один li, при повторном нажатии не удалять предыдущую информацию и новый текст переносить на следующий li и т.д.

Спасибо!

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = myClick;

function myClick() {
  let a = document.querySelector(".myInput").value;
  document.querySelector(".textOutput").innerHTML = prepare(a);
  document.querySelector(".myInput").value = '';
}

function prepare(text) {
  return text
    .split(' ')
    .map(word => {
      if (word.length === 0) {
        return word;
      }
      let color = '';
      if (word.length > 3) {
        color = 'green';
      }
      if (word.match(/[!@#$&*%]/)) {
        color = 'red';
      }
      return `<ul style="color: ${color}">${word}</ul>`;
    }).join(' ');
}
```

```html
<div class="inputblock">
  <input type="text" class="myInput" placeholder="Enter the text">
  <button class="clickButton">Click</button>
</div>
<ul class="textOutput">
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Казалось бы, `.innerHTML = prepare(a)` заменить на `.innerHTML += prepare(a)` и ура, работает. Но использованный здесь `+=` заново перезапишет весь HTML вместе с добавленным куском. На простых примерах это не так заметно, а на каком-нибудь `document.body.innerHTML +=` будет грубой ошибкой.

Вместо него, можно использовать `.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", prepare(a))` ( [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) ) который вставит только полученный кусок от `prepare(a)`

```js
first("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let val = first(".myInput").value.trim();
  if (!val) return; // ничего не ввели? Прервать.

  first(".textOutput").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", prepare(val));
  first(".myInput").value = '';
});

function prepare(text) {
  return "<li>" + text.split(/\s+/).map(wrap_span).join(" ") + "</li>";
  // в регулярном выражении, \s+ =один или много пробелов подряд
  
  /***/
  function wrap_span(word) {    
    let color = /[!@#$&*%]/.test(word) ? "red" : word.length > 3 ? "green" : "";

    return `<span style="color: ${ color }">${ word }</span>`;
  }
}

function first(str) {
  return document.querySelector(str);
}
```

```html
<div class="inputblock">
  <input type="text" class="myInput" placeholder="Enter the text">
  <button class="clickButton"> Click </button>
</div>
<ul class="textOutput"></ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. В данном случае ответы сохраняются, но при этом если в input введено несколько слов, то все они размещаются на отдельных li (в том числе и пробелы). А как подправить так, чтобы весь текст из input переносился на отдельный li?

Comment: @ИльяЛотоцкий А как должна выглядеть подсветка, если все слова внутри одного li ? Тогда каждое слово надо будет завернуть в div / span внутри li ?

Comment: Суть в том, чтобы текст из инпута переносился каждый раз отдельной строкой (все что ввели в инпут, все это в одной строке и переносится). При этом, подсвечиваются зеленым слова где более 3х символов и подсвечиваются красным слова, в которых присутствуют спецсимволы. Ну а остальные слова остаются неизменными.
Сейчас, с вашей помощью, как раз всё работает, единственная проблема в разбивке слов по отдельности. Может тогда не привязываться к li, а просто отдельными строками сделать? Какой способ проще?

Comment: @ИльяЛотоцкий Обновил. Да, span как-раз и предназначен для изменения стилей текста. Сами слова можно завернуть в span, а всё сообщение - в li.

Comment: Супер. Большое спасибо за помощь.